# Vim ignores "set hlsearch" in vimrc. Setting manually works fine

Tags: vim

I may be wrong, but I seem to recall hlsearch being on by default.

Setting it explicitly in .vimrc has no effect, though running
`:set hlsearch`
within vim turns on highlighting as expected.

I've checked `/etc/vimrc` and `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim`  (this is on Arch Linux by the way) just in case but neither one seems to contain anything that unsets hlsearch or something.

The hlsearch setting seems to be getting read from `~/.viminfo` but vim for some reason is turning hlsearch off once I quit it (.viminfo is writable. I've checked).

Comment: Run `:verb set hls?` to find out where it was last modified.  The option is reset when `compatible` is set.  See also `:h viminfo-h` for another pitfall.

Comment: @SatoKatsura You should post that as an answer (because it is the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an answer as requested:

Run `:verb set hls?` to find out where `hlsearch` it was last modified.

According to the manual, setting `compatible` resets `hlsearch`. See also `:h viminfo-h` for another pitfall.

Comment: `:verbose` isn't producing any output at all. and `compatible` isn't set anywhere afaik